# É correto responder uma pergunta com um comentário

Tags: debate, suporte

Percebo que em algumas perguntas, usuários respondem a pergunta através de um comentário ao invés de publicar uma resposta de fato.

É correto fazer esse tipo de coisa? Como a comunidade trata esses casos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu vejo casos diferentes onde é possivel ou aconselhável responder por comentários:

- quem ajuda está com pressa e não tem tempo de dar uma resposta completa
- incerteza sobre a pergunta e/ou a resposta certa naquele caso

Uma vez verificado que o comentário está certo, ie "é a resposta" podem acontecer estes cenários:

- quem respondeu esquece a pergunta e nunca mais volta
- já há outra resposta e o comentário transformado em resposta iria ser visto como duplicado
- quem deu o comentário não conhece o assunto tão bem que esteja confiante em escrever uma resposta e defendê-la

A meu ver, quem chegar depois e vir uma resposta certa nos comentários pode por gentilieza informar o autor e convidá-lo a deixar uma resposta. Mas imagino que haja quem se atire há resposta na mesma. Ás vezes as coisas acontecem tão rápido que nem damos por elas...